# Factoring matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_k$ for $k$ composite?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, computational-algebra

Say you have some matrix $C\in\mathbb{Z}_k^{n\times m}$, where $k$ is composite, and say the rank of $C$ is $r$.
Moreover, say that you have some prior knowledge that $C$ can be written as $C = AB$, where $A\in\mathbb{Z}_k^{n\times r}, B\in\mathbb{Z}_k^{r\times m}$, and $B$ is known to you. How might you go about finding $A$?

If these were matricies over a finite field, the answer would be quite simple:

1. Take the rank decomposition of $C = A' B'$.
2. Find the hermite normal form $H'$ of $B'$, and the transformation $U'$ such that $U'B' = H'$
3. Repeat with $B$ to find $H, U$ such that $UB = H$
4. The uniqueness of the hermite normal form should imply that $H = H'$, so $$C = A' B' = A' U'^{-1}UB$$
   The answer is therefore $A = A' {U'}^{-1}U$.

I'm curious what can be done for matricies over $\mathbb{Z}_k$. The above algorithm fails in Sage at least as HNF computations are not implemented over this space (although I don't know if this is a fundamental limitation).

Comment: I've only superficially thought about your problem, but I don't see an obstruction to using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to replace solving over $\Bbb{Z}_k$ with solving over $\Bbb{Z}_{p^m}$ for each prime power in $k$'s factorization and assembling the results.  Is there such an obstruction?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not sure. I haven't seen a version of CRT for matricies explicitly, but it seems reasonable to reconstruct each $A_{p^e}$ and then set $A = \sum_{p^e} \delta_{p^e} A_{p^e}$, where $\delta_{p^e}$ is the "lagrange coefficient" $(k/p^e)^{-1}\mod p^e$.

Comment: The aforementioned equation is slightly wrong (and I can no longer edit it), instead $A = \sum_{p^e} (k/p^e) \delta_{p^e} A_{p^e}$.

Comment: @EricTowers There are at least two potential issues with this --- 1. $r = \rank_{\mathbb{Z}_k} C$. For this plan to work, this rank would likely have to be the same over each CRT factor $\mathbb{Z}_{p^e}$, which seems unlikely. 2. Generically $R\mod p^e$ may be different as well. In this way one would have to "simultaneously lift" the $A_{p^e}$ solutions, and the $R_{p^e}$ values used to compute them.

Comment: If you assume that decompositions $B = \sum_{p^e} (k/p^e) \delta_{p^e} B_{p^e}$ and $A = \sum_{p^e} (k/p^e) \delta_{p^e} A_{p^e}$ exist, one gets that $C = AB = \sum_{p^e} (k/p^e)^2 \delta_{p^e}^2 A_{p^e} B_{p^e}\mod k$ (as all cross terms should vanish $\bmod k$), which one can then look at $C\bmod p^e\equiv A_{p^e} B_{p^e}$. One could then apply linear algebraic techniques there, then reconstruct with the above formula. This still pre-supposes the ranks are the same in each CRT factor, which feels like it shouldn't be true in general.